# What are /media/[user]/disk, /media/[user]/disk1, etc.?

Tags: mount, snap

These mounted filesystems:

```
$ df /media/ray/d*
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop8         48128 48128         0 100% /media/ray/disk
/dev/loop3         64768 64768         0 100% /media/ray/disk1

$ ls -la /media/ray/d*
/media/ray/disk:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  119 Jun 15 09:43 .
drwxr-x---+  5 root root 4096 Nov 24 12:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   53 Jun 15 09:43 bin
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  110 Jun 15 09:43 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   66 Mar 28  2022 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   43 Jun 15 09:43 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   32 Jun 15 09:43 meta
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   58 Jun 15 09:43 snap
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   62 Feb 17  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   51 Jun 15 09:43 var

/media/ray/disk1:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  336 Aug 26 02:46 .
drwxr-x---+  5 root root 4096 Nov 24 12:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Aug 26 00:34 bin -> usr/bin
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root   70 Aug 26 02:46 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   68 Aug 26 02:46 dev
drwxr-xr-x  43 root root 1578 Aug 26 02:46 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Apr 15  2020 home
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Aug 26 02:46 host
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Aug 26 00:34 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Aug 26 00:34 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Aug 26 00:34 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   10 Aug 26 00:34 libx32 -> usr/libx32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Aug 26 00:34 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   32 Aug 26 02:46 meta
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Aug 26 00:34 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Aug 26 00:34 opt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Apr 15  2020 proc
drwx------   2 root root   46 Aug 26 02:46 root
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  124 Aug 26 02:46 run
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Aug 26 00:34 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   58 Aug 26 02:46 snap
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Aug 26 00:34 srv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Apr 15  2020 sys
drwxrwxrwt   2 root root    3 Aug 26 02:46 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  205 Aug 26 02:46 usr
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  159 Aug 26 02:46 var
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    3 Aug 26 02:46 writable
```

seem to be used by `snap`:

```
$ sudo lsof  /media/ray/disk

$ sudo lsof /media/ray/disk1
snap-stor 1099326  ray  rtd    DIR    7,3      336 11882 /
snap-stor 1099326  ray  mem    REG    7,3           6140 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.31.so (path dev=259,2, inode=21499031)
snap-stor 1099326  ray  mem    REG    7,3           6146 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2 (path dev=259,2, inode=21506717)
…
```

The system is up-to-date Ubuntu 20.04.

My last three reboots were:

- 2022-04-04 20:57:06 -0400 Mon # Replace UPS battery
- 2022-05-21 18:47:01 -0400 Sat # 6-hour blackout
- 2022-09-04 09:35:24 -0400 Sun # 1-hour blackout

so both were created within the same continuous uptime period.

What are they and what happens if I unmount them?