# /media/(user)/disk magically appeared and I can't unmount it

Tags: mount, 22.04, snap

This may be similar to [What are /media/[user]/disk, /media/[user]/disk1, etc.?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442369/what-are-media-user-disk-media-user-disk1-etc) which was asked 10 months ago but no one answered.

I was just using my Ubuntu Studio 22.04 machine with XFCE 4.16. and suddenly noticed there's an extra "509 MB volume" with the label `disk`, i.e., `/media/(myuser)/disk`.

Here are the contents of `/media/dlm/disk/`:

```
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/
command-chain  data-dir  etc  gnome-platform  lib  meta  sbin  snap  usr  var
$ $ ls /media/dlm/disk/command-chain/
desktop-launch  hooks-configure-fonts
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/data-dir/
icons  sounds  themes
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/etc/
bindresvport.blacklist  fonts     gnome    init.d      ld.so.conf.d  profile.d  sensors3.conf  X11
emacs                   gai.conf  gtk-3.0  ld.so.conf  presage.xml   pulse      sensors.d      xdg
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/gnome-platform/
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/lib/
udev  x86_64-linux-gnu
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/meta
gui  snap.yaml
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/sbin
ldconfig  ldconfig.real
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/snap
manifest.yaml  snapcraft.yaml
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/usr
bin  lib  libexec  sbin  share
$ ls /media/dlm/disk/var
lib
```

I don't remember doing anything to mount an archive or any other volume. I mean, I guess it's harmless? But... I didn't ask for it, so it shouldn't happen, and if it does happen, it should be reversible.

For tidiness' sake, I'd like to unmount it, but the volume is "busy".

So I wonder. Who created this volume? Who is using it so that it's busy?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but they kind of look like snap mounts.  Maybe try running `mount | grep disk` and see if it shows how they are mounted.

Comment: Indeed: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_126.snap (deleted) on /media/dlm/disk type squashfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,uhelper=udisks2) -- "deleted" but not unmounted either

Comment: Someone else was / is experiencing the exact same issue:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1487497/why-suddenly-appears-mounted-the-media-username-disk  and I am trying to help them as well.  Looks like this might be a snap issue.  But I did leave them a comment there that might have helped, but I haven't seen a response back yet.

Comment: Exactly the same revision... OK, I tried `sudo snap remove gnome-42-2204 --revision 126` and it says "revision 126 of snap 'gnome-42-2204' is not installed" (which is consistent with `snap list --all` output). However the offending mount disappeared after reboot. So, reboot seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It now mounts automatically when USB stick is inserted. More user frieandly.

`lsof` or similar utility will show which process prevents it unmount.

Comment: It isn't a USB stick -- it remained after ejecting removable media.