# Why suddenly appears mounted the /media/username/disk?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, directory, home-directory, fhs

For

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Just today, few minutes ago through the `Dock`, I did do realize that was mounted the `/media/username/disk` location with the following content:

```
command-chain  data-dir  etc  gnome-platform  lib  meta  sbin  snap  usr  var
```

The mounted location has a size of 509MB ... Is possible umounted through the `Files` window but the item remains in the `Dock` and `Files` window unmounted

**Question**

- Why suddenly appears mounted the `/media/username/disk`?

Is it normal? How to disappear that icon from the `Dock`?

**More Details**

When is executed the `mount | grep disk` command appears:

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_126.snap (deleted) on /media/manueljordan/disk type squashfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,errors=continue,threads=single,uhelper=udisks2)
```

When is executed the `lsblk -ap -o +MODEL` command appears:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS                            MODEL
/dev/loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5                           
/dev/loop1    7:1    0  18.4M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/30               
/dev/loop2    7:2    0   9.4M  1 loop /snap/chromium-ffmpeg/34               
/dev/loop3    7:3    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2785                      
/dev/loop4    7:4    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974                      
/dev/loop5    7:5    0  55.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/2790                      
/dev/loop6    7:6    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015                      
/dev/loop7    7:7    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858                       
/dev/loop8    7:8    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/864                       
/dev/loop9    7:9    0 137.8M  1 loop /snap/drawio/184                       
/dev/loop10   7:10   0   137M  1 loop /snap/drawio/186                       
/dev/loop11   7:11   0   186M  1 loop /snap/opera/263                        
/dev/loop12   7:12   0 236.9M  1 loop /snap/firefox/3131                     
/dev/loop13   7:13   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/194              
/dev/loop14   7:14   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198              
/dev/loop15   7:15   0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140              
/dev/loop16   7:16   0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143              
/dev/loop17   7:17   0 485.5M  1 loop /media/manueljordan/disk               
/dev/loop18   7:18   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535           
/dev/loop19   7:19   0 240.5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/3206                     
/dev/loop20   7:20   0   497M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/141                
/dev/loop21   7:21   0     0B  1 loop                                        
/dev/loop22   7:22   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638                   
/dev/loop23   7:23   0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959                   
/dev/loop24   7:24   0  40.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20092                      
/dev/loop25   7:25   0  40.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19993                      
/dev/loop26   7:26   0   428K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/57     
/dev/loop27   7:27   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83     
/dev/loop28   7:28   0 320.4M  1 loop /snap/vlc/3078                         
/dev/loop29   7:29   0 496.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/132                
/dev/loop30   7:30   0   186M  1 loop /snap/opera/261                        
/dev/sda      8:0    0 698.6G  0 disk                                        ST750LM022 HN-M750MBB
├─/dev/sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi                              
└─/dev/sda2   8:2    0 698.1G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell 
                                      /                                      
/dev/sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom                                         hp DVDRAM GT80N
```

Comment: It might be a snap app mounted.  Try running `mount | grep disk` from a command line and see if it shows what is mounted at that location.

Comment: Edit your post and add the output of `$ lsblk -ap -o +MODEL` to it. This should be easier to read than the output of mount.

Comment: Terrance and Hannu, see the _More Details_ section. Thank You

Comment: Strange that a deleted snap is hanging on like that.  Maybe try running `sudo snap remove gnome-42-2204 --revision 126` then you might need to reboot the system afterwards.  The command of `snap list --all` should show you all revisions of the snaps installed.  I don't recommend removing the newest revision of a snap.

Comment: Should I do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` first? and then do a restart of the system?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to try that.  You can also try a `sudo snap refresh` to see if there might be any updates lingering as well before a restart.

Comment: Were executed the 2 `apt` commands and nothing, later the `sudo snap refresh` command and shown that all is up dated... and the icon remains in the `Dock` yet - well finally the laptop was restarted and that icon disappeared .... not sure what happened ...

Answer (score 0):

Manual:  I have found if the mount point doesn’t connect quickly enough it tends to put files in my /mnt (your /media).

I’ve mostly reduced this problem by adding to the /etc/fstab mount statement:
noauto,x-systemd.automount

(Note the punctuation! That’s a comma, hyphen, then period.)

Comment: Pls, read the latest comment of the OP. Thanks for your answer too